# Plotting xts data with trend line

Tags: r, xts

I am trying to plot a xts data (annual rainfall) and add a trend line (e.g. Loess) on top of it. Can someone please suggest option to plot the trend line without needing to convert the xts to ts.

Example data:

```
>RainXts
            Rf
1978-12-31  1416.95
1979-12-31  881.152
1980-12-31  1437.75
1981-12-31  881.10
1982-12-31  966.07
1983-12-31  1387.61
1984-12-31  1013.58
1985-12-31  1180.57
1986-12-31  1162.35
1987-12-31  883.92
1988-12-31  955.84
1989-12-31  828.472
1990-12-31  1208.72
1991-12-31  1324.72
1992-12-31  1096.2
1993-12-31  1454.64
1994-12-31  874.64
1995-12-31  941.92
1996-12-31  883.92
1997-12-31  793.44
```

Note: Converting the xts to ts object and using the command below works (where RainTs = as.ts(RainXts))

```
lines(lowess(time(RainTs),RainTs),col="red")
```

Comment: I just realised that, when the xts package is not loaded to the library, the plot command plots the time series (without proper date/year display rather as a simple sequential numbers) but subsequent line(lowess()) command adds the line as expected.
However, as soon as the xts package is attached to the library, the plot command plots the series correctly including display of proper Date but the subsequent lines(lowess()) comnand doesn't work. 
Any solution to get them both right, please.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an quick way with ggplot, if you convert your data as a data.frame, with `df$date  <- as.Date(rownames(RainXts))`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(date, Rf)) + 
      geom_point() + 
      stat_smooth()
```

[image]

Data frame used:

```
df<- structure(list(Rf = c(1416.95, 881.152, 1437.75, 881.1, 966.07, 
1387.61, 1013.58, 1180.57, 1162.35, 883.92, 955.84, 828.472, 
1208.72, 1324.72, 1096.2, 1454.64, 874.64, 941.92, 883.92, 793.44
), date = structure(c(3286, 3651, 4017, 4382, 4747, 5112, 5478, 
5843, 6208, 6573, 6939, 7304, 7669, 8034, 8400, 8765, 9130, 9495, 
9861, 10226), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Rf", 
"date"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Adam. But I was trying to (can we?) plot the trend line without needing to convert xts to dataframe or ts. 
(I have lots of rainfall stations and xts objects for multiple time scales, so want to reduce the number of requirement to create further objects, if possible).